# React - Make an FAQ class toggle on click

Tags: reactjs

I am creating an FAQ with React and I have the questions in `strong` tags and the answers in `p` tags. On click of the `strong` tags I would like to add a class of `active` to the clicked tag. I am close but there is some sort of scope issue on my toggle function and I'm not sure how to move past it:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./faq.css";

class Questions extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active: false
    };
  }

  toggleClass() {
    const currentState = this.state.active;
    this.setState({ active: !currentState });
  }

  render() {
    let faq = [
      {
        question: "Lorem",
        answer: "Ipsum"
      },
      {
        question: "Dolor",
        answer: "Sit"
      }
    ];

    return (
      <div className="questions">
        {faq.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="item">
              <strong
                className={this.state.active ? "active" : null}
                onClick={this.toggleClass}
              >
                {item.question}
              </strong>
              <p>{item.answer}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Questions;
```

[Here's what I have so far](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-pascal-8dxxi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind `toogleClass` method to the `Questions` instance:

**Opition one: Using `bind`**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./faq.css";

class Questions extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active: false
    };
    this.toggleClass.bind(this)

  }

  toggleClass() {
    const currentState = this.state.active;
    this.setState({ active: !currentState });
  }

  render() {
    let faq = [
      {
        question: "Lorem",
        answer: "Ipsum"
      },
      {
        question: "Dolor",
        answer: "Sit"
      }
    ];

    return (
      <div className="questions">
        {faq.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="item">
              <strong
                className={this.state.active ? "active" : null}
                onClick={this.toggleClass}
              >
                {item.question}
              </strong>
              <p>{item.answer}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Questions;
```

**Option 2: Using class property initializer**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./faq.css";

class Questions extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active: false
    };
    this.toggleClass.bind(this)

  }

  toggleClass = () => {
    const currentState = this.state.active;
    this.setState({ active: !currentState });
  }

  render() {
    let faq = [
      {
        question: "Lorem",
        answer: "Ipsum"
      },
      {
        question: "Dolor",
        answer: "Sit"
      }
    ];

    return (
      <div className="questions">
        {faq.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="item">
              <strong
                className={this.state.active ? "active" : null}
                onClick={this.toggleClass}
              >
                {item.question}
              </strong>
              <p>{item.answer}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Questions;
```

To selected only the active question you can do this:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./faq.css";

class Questions extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeQuestion: null
    };
  }

  render() {
    let faq = [
      {
        question: "Lorem",
        answer: "Ipsum"
      },
      {
        question: "Dolor",
        answer: "Sit"
      }
    ];

    return (
      <div className="questions">
        {faq.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="item">
              <strong
                data-question={item.question}
                className={
                  item.question === this.state.activeQuestion ? "active" : null
                }
                onClick={() => {
                  console.log(item.question);
                  this.setState({ activeQuestion: item.question });
                }}
              >
                {item.question}
              </strong>
              <p>{item.answer}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Questions;
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea how I can modify it so that it only adds the class to the one that was clicked? Currently it is adding it to every `strong` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `toggleClass` needs to be an arrow function -> `toggleClass = () => {...your code here...}`.  When it's a regular function the outer scope (where this.state is), is not being passed to your function.  Without an arrow function, when you refer to `this` you are referring only to the scope of the `toggleClass` function, where state does not exist and so is undefined.

[Working Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-sanderson-4mg0b)

Also due to setState being async, it's best practice to use current state by referencing it within the setState function like below:

```
toggleClass = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        active: !prevState.active
    })
}
```

When you reference state outside of the setState function then pass it in, it's possible that the state would be different by the time you use it to set it.
i.e. say the currentState you got was true, and then your setState uses current state to set the opposite (False) by the time setState tries to set it, something else might have changed your existing state to False already and you are just setting it to False again (instead of modifying what the current state is at that time which would be False and you want want True). Unlikely in your case, but it is good practice to follow this because you might run into this issue elsewhere

Comment: Thank you, any idea how I can modify it so that it only adds the class to the one that was clicked? Currently it is adding it to every strong tag, which makes sense now that I think about it because they're all using the same state.

Comment: That's because your state is globally set not per item.  You could make a new class for each list item, and manage the state for each list item individually there. I've modified the [code here for that](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-sanderson-4mg0b)